# How to hide unused member pages from public/google

Tags: templates, members, google

I recently discovered that member pages for my EE site are showing up in Google search results, even though I'm not currently using members (beyond super admins) and I have no public member page templates.

Here's an example of the page I'm seeing: http://www.weddingwise.co.nz/member/1

Is there any way to hide all pages with "member" in segment1 so they are not visible to public or to Google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Members -> Preferences in the control panel, you can set the Profile Triggering Word (see [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/membership_preferences.html#profile-triggering-word)) to `%` which will make them completely inaccessible from the frontend.

Another technique is to configure it randomly in the config.php like this:

```
$config['profile_trigger'] = rand(0,time());
```

Comment: Great thanks. Your first option worked like a charm.